# Erro javascript, função para de funcionar quando acrescento outra

Tags: javascript, ajax

O código a seguir para de funcionar quando acrescento outro praticamente igual.
Embora a primeira parte funcione perfeitamente, ao inserir uma continuação com a lógica parecida nem mesmo a primeira parte funciona.

### Tenho o seguinte form:

```js
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){
  try{
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
        }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
            }catch(falha){
             request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
    return request;
}

function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Nome já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
    }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="valida_user_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form_user_cad" name="form_user_cad" method="POST"  action="recebe_form_user.php" >
 <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome" autofocus onblur="nome_existe()"><br/>
 <input type="text" id="input_email_cad" name="email_cad" placeholder="Insira o Email" onblur="email_existe()"><br/>
 <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta"  >
</form>
```

*Funciona normal, o usuário passa pelo regex e pelo banco, se digitou correto e o nome não existe, avança para o próximo campo email.*

### Dúvida, por que quando eu insiro a próxima função nada funciona?

***próxima função que é sequencia com a anterior.***

```js
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){
  try{
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
        }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
            }catch(falha){
             request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
    return request;
}

function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Nome já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
    }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
function email_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_email()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var email = document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?email_cad=" + email, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Email já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}

function valida_email(){
 var filter_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i ;
 if(!filter_email.test(document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = "Email inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_email(){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = null;
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="valida_user_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form_user_cad" name="form_user_cad" method="POST"  action="recebe_form_user.php" >
 <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome" autofocus onblur="nome_existe()"><br/>
 <input type="text" id="input_email_cad" name="email_cad" placeholder="Insira o Email" onblur="email_existe()"><br/>
 
 <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta"  >
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade de comentar a linha com problema, mas é essa daqui:

```
document.getElementById("input_email_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_email(){
```

Nela você está abrindo "inicializando" uma função (`keydown_email()`), porém não está fechando as chaves da função `valuda_email()` acima dela.

Basta colocar as chaves após o `return true;` e pronto.

```js
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){
  try{
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
        }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
            }catch(falha){
             request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
    return request;
}

function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Nome já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
    }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}

  function email_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_email()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var email = document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?email_cad=" + email, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Email já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}

function valida_email(){
 var filter_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i ;
 if(!filter_email.test(document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = "Email inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
    //Seu problema está nesta linha abaixo. Está abrindo uma função mas não está fechando as chaves do if().
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_email(){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = null;
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
      }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="valida_user_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form_user_cad" name="form_user_cad" method="POST"  action="recebe_form_user.php" >
 <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome" autofocus onblur="nome_existe()"/><br/>
 <input type="text" id="input_email_cad" name="email_cad" placeholder="Insira o Email" onblur="email_existe()"/><br/>
 
 <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta"  >
</form>
```

> Vale ressaltar que existe formas melhores de fazer essas validações.